# asymptotic estimate for sum over prime numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

> Prove that $\sum_{p \text{ prime}, p\leq n, p \equiv 3\mod 4} \frac{\log p}p = \frac{\log n}2+O(1)$.

I need to show that for n large enough, we can find a constant $c$ so that $\sum_{p \text{ prime}, p\leq n, p \equiv 3\mod 4} \frac{\log p}p \leq \frac{\log n}2 + c.$ By Dirichlet's theorem, the sum makes sense, as there are infinitely many primes congruent to $3\mod 4.$ There is a generalization of this result [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59996/sum-of-log-p-p-for-p-equivalent-to-l-mod-d), but it's not clear how the generalization was derived. I also think that this problem should be easier than the generalized version and should not require character theory. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can prove this result?

Comment: Apostol's intro to analytic number theory proves this statement exactly (the entirety of chapter 7 is dedicated to proving the generalization you linked). I am not sure of a simpler way, but Im sure there is one.